# Node isDirectory() not working properly or i am missing somenthing

Tags: file, node.js, sockets, directory

I want to get all names of files and directories from path and recognize them as files and directories. but When i run my code sometimes it works and somentimes it shows that directories are files. Here is the code

```
socket.on('data',function(path){
  fs.readdir('path',function(err, data) {
    var filestatus=[];
    var z=0;
    var i=data.length-1;

    data.forEach(function(file){ 
      fs.stat(file, function(err, stats) {  
        filestatus[z]=stats.isDirectory()
        if (z==i){
          socket.emit('backinfo',{names:data,status:filestatus});
        }
        z++;
      })
    })
  })  
})
```

During tests i realized that when i slow down data.forEach loop (using console.log(something) it works better(less miss). And this is strange.

Comment: 1. Note that `fs.readdir`'s result is just names, not full pathes. 2. Shouldn't you increment `z` before checking its equality with `i`? 3. Check out [async](https://github.com/caolan/async).

Comment: You're not checking `err` in the `fs.stat` callback and as elmigranto pointed out, `file` is just the file names, not paths so you need to prepend `path` to those names when calling `fs.stat`.

Answer (score 1):

**This is about 96% incorrect, thank you to  JohnnyHK for pointing out my mistake, see the comments below for the real problem / solution.**

Because the fs.stat() function call is asynchronous, the operations on the filestatus array are overlapping. You should either use the **[async](https://github.com/caolan/async)** library as elmigranto suggested, or switch to using fs.statSync.

More details on what's happening:

When you call fs.stat(), it basically runs in the background and then immediately goes onto the next line of code. When it has got the details of the file, it then calls the callback function, which in your code is the function where you add the information to the filestatus array.

Because fs.stat() doesn't wait before returning, your program is going through the data array very quickly, and mutliple callbacks are being run simultanously and causing issues because the z variable isn't being incremented straight away, so

```
filestatus[z]=stats.isDirectory()
```

could be executed multiple times by different callbacks before z gets incremented.

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: yes it make sense - its is exactly what I thought, but was not sure. Thanks for answere.

Comment: This is not a correct answer.  Node.js is single-threaded so nothing in your code happens simultaneously.  Each callback runs to completion before the next one occurs so the incrementing of `z` is fine.

Comment: @JohnnyHK shit, you're completely right. However, I think that Kriss is assuming that the names and the status arrays will be in the same order, which won't be true because the order of the callbacks is not fixed. 

So I was totally wrong about multiple callbacks being executed simultaneously, however the callbacks are being executed out of order which means that the filestatus array won't match the array of names. Right?

Comment: Right, and that's a good point about the order of the elements in `filestatus`.  It would probably be better to make that an object instead, keyed by file name: `filestatus[file] = stats.isDirectory();`

Answer (score 0):

you are using for statement in NODEJS and this will work if turned the For Statement to recursive function please see the attached code for help

---

```
function load_Files(pat,callback) {
console.log("Searching Path is: "+ph);
fs.readdir(pat,(err,files)=>
{
    if(err)
    {
        callback(err);
    }
    else
    {
        var onlydir=[];
        var onlyfiles=[];
        var d=(index)=>
            {
                if (index==files.length)
                    {
                        console.log("last index: "+ index);

                        var ar=[];
                        ar.concat(onlydir,onlyfiles);
                        callback(null,ar);
                        return;
                    }
                fs.stat(files[index],(err,status)=>
                    {
                        console.log("the needed file " +files[index]);
                    if (status.isDirectory())
                        {
                        onlydir.push(files[index]);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            onlyfiles.push(files[index]);
                        }

                        console.log("only Directory: "+onlydir.length);
                        console.log("index: "+ index);
                        d(index+1);

                    }
                )

            }
        d(0);
    }
});
```

}

Comment: why is recursive better than for in this case? Plus, please format code with less spaces for identation, it will be better to read here